# problems with points_and_lines tutorial

Tags: ros, rviz, tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new to Ubuntu and ROS and I'm trying to use your tutorial to get myself started with rviz and ROS visualization capabilities.  Ultimately I want to read from SICK LiDAR and visualize the point clouds generated from that.

I am encountering errors trying to run the tutorial [here](http://ros.org/wiki/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Points%20and%20Lines), and hoped you could help me.

First in my ros_workspace I created a package using_markers

Then I created a file points_and_lines.cpp and pasted your code into it

I then copied points_and_lines.cpp into an srv folder in the using_markers package using roscp

This all executed without a problem

Where I began encountering issues was when I tried to execute rosmake on the file as instructed in the tutorial.  14/15 operations execute, but the 15th fails issuing the warning WARNING: Skipped command line arguments: ['points_and_lines.cpp'] because they could not be resolved to a stack name or a package name.

As I said I am new to Linux and ROS and I imagine I have made some strange syntax errror; have you ever encountered this before and how can I resolve it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31713/problems-with-points_and_lines-tutorial/) by [macduffproffitt](https://answers.ros.org/users/2173/macduffproffitt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please always copy-paste the exact commands you were using. It's always hard to guess what you did just from the error messages.

It looks like you called `rosmake points_and_lines.cpp`. This is not how it works. You need to create a ros package, copy your source file into it, edit CMakeLists.txt and create a binary target and rosmake your package. Have a look at [this](http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage) and [this](http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) tutorial.

Btw. for just visualizing laser or point-cloud data, you don't need to program anything. RViz already has plugins for doing visualizing this data.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1